# C# WPF code runs faster in Visual Studio than from console, and slower from another folder

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, visual-studio

This is the strangest problem I've ever seen, and I hope you find it interesting.  I've created a C# WPF example that listens to IP packets as a typical packet sniffer (source below), and prints some data to the screen.  I have very consistent and repeatable behavior, but with two results (fast and slow).

**Prerequisite**: Running Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator because of the IP socket code.

If I run the application in Visual Studio (clicking green arrow) in x86 Release mode it processes about 300 packets per second (fast).  Perfect.  If I run it in Debug mode it processes about 1 packet per second (slow).  This is understandable since debug mode adds overhead.  But, hang on, this is where it gets strange.

**Problems/Questions**:

1. If I copy the solution to another folder and run (x86 Release just as before) from within Visual Studio it runs slowly.  But, if I copy the same solution back to the original folder path, it runs fast. Why?
2. If I run the x86 Release mode executable as admin from the command prompt it processes about 1 per second (slow). Why?  (Edit: This may be due to fact that any performance gains from the VS hosting process don't exist outside of VS.)

So, the code only executes fast if it's run from Visual Studio (x86 Release) in the original folder.

**Additional things I've tried:**

1. Cleaned and manually whacked the obj and bin folders... and rebuilt solution.
2. Cleaned the registry and deleted all lines referring to the application or path.
3. Removed all entries in the Windows Firewall that refer to the application name.
4. Disabled antivirus software and added the application to the exclusion list.
5. Run diff comparisons (BeyondCompare) of the Visual Studio output text.
6. Created new solutions and copy/pasted code into them and they still run slowly if not the same name or in the same folder.
7. Compared to WireShark capture which displays about 300 packets per second.
8. Enabled/Disabled VS host process. Enabled runs faster if solution is in original path only.
9. Rebooted

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfSingle.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace WpfSingle
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            private static System.Threading.Thread _processingThread;
            private bool _killThread;
            private Socket _socket;
            private const int PACKET_MAX_SIZE = 32768;
            private byte[] _bytesIn;
            private byte[] _bytesOut;
            private byte[] _byteData;
            private int _bytesReceived;
            private int _packetCounter;
            private string Interface = "192.168.1.42";
            private StringBuilder _sbTextOut;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                _sbTextOut = new StringBuilder();

                try
                {
                    _processingThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ThreadProcess);
                    _processingThread.Start();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void ThreadProcess()
            {
                _killThread = false;
                _byteData = new byte[PACKET_MAX_SIZE];
                _bytesIn = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                _bytesOut = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                _packetCounter = 0;

                try
                {
                    _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
                    _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Interface), 0));
                    _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
                    _socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, _bytesIn, _bytesOut);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (_socket != null) _socket.Close();
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    OnThreadProcess();
                    if (_killThread)
                        break;
                }
            }

            private void OnThreadProcess()
            {
                if (_socket != null)
                {
                    EndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0) as EndPoint;
                    try
                    {
                        _bytesReceived = _socket.ReceiveFrom(_byteData, _byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ep);
                        if (_bytesReceived > 0)
                        {
                            _packetCounter++;
                            if (_packetCounter >= 300) _killThread = true;

                            _sbTextOut.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} : {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}", DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss.ffffff"), _packetCounter, _byteData[0], _byteData[1], _byteData[2], _byteData[3], _byteData[4], _byteData[5]));
                            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                textBlock1.Text = _sbTextOut.ToString(); 
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                _killThread = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using Explorer I simply copied the folder with the solution to another folder name.

Comment: "The folder"  does not tell me much.

Comment: it's wellknown that the `Debug.Print` or any other writer writing something to console/output window will slow down everything. I've experienced this kind of slowing. You should try writing to some log text file instead.

Comment: Agreed, but I did say it runs very fast in Visual Studio.  This is only an example of the problem, and even if I comment out the Dispatcher line and set a breakpoint on _packetCounter I'll see the same behavior.

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` gets omitted from the compilation in Release mode, so if exceptions are being caught, nothing will be logged.  Switch over to `Console.Error.WriteLine` and see if there are any errors occurring when you run in the alternate folder.

Comment: Good point.  I changed each of the 3 WriteLines to Console.Error.WriteLine and set breakpoints at each.  They never hit and processing is still slow.  Additionally, I made the same changes to the original solution and it also does not hit breakpoints and runs very fast.

Comment: Break points will not get hit in Release mode unless you set your options different from the defaults.

Comment: Absolutely.  the breakpoints were set in debug mode, and did not hit.  Release mode in original path is fast, debug mode is slow and doesn't hit breakpoints.

Comment: Does the code actually *run correctly* in release mode in the original path?  Maybe the fast one is the one that's actually failing.  Also, try disabling all your breakpoints and see if the performance changes.  And don't trust breakpoints in Release mode anyway--watch the Output window to see if any errors are logged.

Comment: Yes, the code runs correctly (fast) in release mode in the original path. But no other path, nor from command line.  I suppose the fast one could be broken.  With all breakpoints removed I see the same consistent behavior.  Thanks for the good ideas.

Comment: Yes most of the times, code will run faster it's run from Visual Studio, as VS Hosting process comes into the picture and will run the code in 'Partial Trust'. Try disabling the VS Hosting process. Project-->Properties-->Debug Tab-->Uncheck Enable VS Hosting Process

Comment: I think Kris is on to the answer. By disabling the hosting process, all configurations are now running slowly. So, VS with the hosting process in Release may result in a faster app. However, it doesn't explain why running from another folder in VS with the process hosting enabled it still runs slow. if it was consistent behavior I'd say Kris solved it. Then I'd be wondering how to get the performance/caching benefits of vshost in my example so it always runs fast

Comment: There is a pretty serious fire-hose problem in this code.  Surely the perception of "slower" is actually packet loss.

Comment: Yes Hans, that is correct.  In release, it is processing all packets (confirmed with wireshark sxs comparison).  In debug, or outside of VS, or from another folder, it is running slower and dropping packets.

Comment: Reading about the hosting process a little, it seems to serialize state between runs to facilitate faster startup (among other things). So it may be possible that the hosting process simply isn't caching its state in the other path. Are any network paths involved? Are there zombie instances of the hosting process still running before you start your tests?

Comment: No network paths, the code is all local.  No zombie instances of Vs, or vshosts.exe.  I've even rebooted the PC with same consistent result.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code is now capturing at a slow rate in all configurations.  I can no longer get 300/sec packet captures.  It is now running/capturing about 2-3/sec.  And yes, i'm using the same source code.  I'm convinced the problem was related to vshosts (thanks Kris).  Unfortunately, I still don't know how to recreate the higher capture rate, and the slower rate is not good enough to be useful.  Obviously it's possible as it was running fast all day... till now.  Thanks all for your help.